# Should we not ask questios we're fairly sure don't have an answer in philosophical literature?

Tags: discussion

Should we not ask questions we're fairly sure don't have an answer in philosophical literature?

Comment: I don't think a question's direct *answer* must pre-exist in the academic literature, but I do think questions should be *answerable* with reference to the academic literature. From your questions on Meta, it seems to me you're looking more for discursive, creative, "what do you think of this idea?", dorm-room style philosophizing, but the kinds of questions and answers this site is set up to serve are more well-defined and -studied than that. The Reddit r/philosophy has the kinds of discussions you seem to yearn for.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the kind of question. *For example*, a question on the implications of an adaptation of a philosophical theory would be perfectly on topic, even if it has not been discussed before.